# Common behavior in class-based unit test: inheritance or shared test fixtures?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I have several test classes to write, that I expect to have quite similar Setup and Teardown code (basically the same methods, but with different arguments). 
From what I understand of the unittest package, it seems that there are two methods for doing such:

- Create a base class inheriting from matlab.unittest.TestCase class, with the common code for Setup and Teardown. Then all my actual test cases classes would extend it.
- Using the shared test fixtures pattern documented [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-test-using-shared-fixtures.html): the fixture would contain common setup/teardown code and be referenced in all test cases classes

After reading Andy Campbell answer, I think it is worth giving some more context to the usecase and our TestSuite organization: the software we are testing in these tests can only be used throughout a simulation bench, meaning this is not actually speaking unit-testing in the sense that we do not test one function at a time. Our testing strategy is as follows:

- Play a simulation scenario with our simulator
- Record simulation output (in a file or in workspace)
- Launch unit-tests on previously recorded simulation output
- At the end of the test sequence, publish additional results about the simulation

Given that simulation are computationally expensive, we cannot afford to launch the simulation before each unittest. On the other hand, as we have one test class for each simulation scenario, the setup/teardown code shall be applied for each test class.

Which one would you advocate for ? The first one seems to me more natural and easier to understand, but I feel like it is maybe not the canonical way to do so.  On the other hand, I am not sure to completely grasp the notion of shared fixture.

Comment: This question is somewhat off-topic here but may fit better on [softwareengineering.se]. However, if you decide to post it there instead, do not re-post it, but instead use a custom mod flag.

Comment: I don't see why this could be off topic. It makes perfect sense to me to be on stack overflow and is right inline with the thousands of other questions posted here. What is the topic of stack overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a semantic difference between shared test fixtures and the setup/teardown code you place into a class and shared via a base class.

First of all, is the setup/teardown code expensive? In other words does it take a long time to execute or have some other reason why executing it fewer times is better? If the setup code is not expensive, then it is indeed better to put it into a `TestMethodSetup` method and share it via inheritance. This will allow you to *share the code* required but it will not share the actual fixture. That is, each test will setup and teardown its own [fresh fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fresh%20Fixture.html). This is great to help ensure independence of tests but is only feasible if the setup is not expensive because it happens every time.

If the fixture is expensive to setup/teardown you will not only want to share the code required to setup/teardown the fixture, but you may also want to share the actual instance of the fixture. That is, you may want to only set it up and tear it down once for all tests that you will run. They will share the same fixture instance itself (in the literature this is known as a [shared fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Shared%20Fixture.html)). If you use a shared fixture, you can still put it in a base class and derived test classes will benefit from its use, but the difference is that the fixture can be shared across test class boundaries. That is if you have something like the following:

**MySharedTestFixture.m**

```
classdef MySharedTestFixture < matlab.unittest.fixtures.Fixture
    methods
        function setup(fixture)
            disp('Setting up expensive fixture');
        end
        function teardown(fixture)
            disp('Tearing down expensive fixture.');
        end
    end
end
```

**BaseTest.m**

```
classdef (Abstract, SharedTestFixtures={MySharedTestFixture}) ...
    BaseTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase

end
```

**FooTest.m**

```
classdef FooTest < BaseTest
    methods(Test)
        function testSomething(testCase)
        end
    end
end
```

**BarTest.m**

```
classdef BarTest < BaseTest
    methods(Test)
        function testSomethingElse(testCase)
        end
    end
end
```

Observe the output of the test run:

```
>> runtests
Setting up MySharedTestFixture
Setting up expensive fixture
Done setting up MySharedTestFixture
__________

Running BarTest
.
Done BarTest
__________

Running FooTest
.
Done FooTest
__________

Tearing down MySharedTestFixture
Tearing down expensive fixture.
Done tearing down MySharedTestFixture
__________
```

You can see that the expensive shared fixture was only setup and torn down once even across classes.

You can use `TestClassSetup/Teardown` methods to share setup/teardown code across all tests in a given class, but these will not share across different tests.

Also, if you want to make a canonical fixture, perhaps because it is something you commonly need to do, you can create it as an official `Fixture` and then decide in specific contexts where you would like them to apply and how widely you would like them to be shared. For example, for the `MySharedTestFixture` class above, I can share it across classes as a `SharedTestFixture`, but I can also share it across just the tests in a given class by calling `applyFixture` in a `TestClassSetup` method. Similarly, I can call `applyFixture` in a `TestMethodSetup` method to create the fixture as a fresh fixture for all tests in the class, and finally, if I just want to use the fixture as a one off in one test method, I can easily just call `applyFixture` on it in the test method that requires it. In this case, the shared code is separable from the degree to which the actual instance is to be shared.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Interesting, it didn't came to my mind that also both options could be combined. Aside the practical aspect (e.g. what should run in which sequence), code organization is essential. Correct me if I am wrong, but fixtures give some kind of extra-modularity in your test code

Comment: Yes, I think that fixtures allow you to avoid encoding the fixture setup/teardown directly in the test code, instead relying on the fixture whose sole job it is to do just that. The test then just decides when and how to setup/teardown the fixtures you have readily available.

It probably doesn't make sense to create a fixture for every different thing you need to setup and teardown, but it should be considered for those things that are very common, expensive (so you would want to share them), and/or difficult to get right.